# Accessing default Tomcat's and Axis2 page

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, tomcat6

I got here WSDL file for a Web service (SOAP) (I can't view the source code though). I want to build Web service client to test the operation available at that Web service. I am using localy Tomcat 6 and Axis2 1.4.
I can view the WSDL file within my local network. Once I import WSDL file and try to generate Java client code for that Web service I receive this exception:

```
Exception occurred while code generation for WSDL  : null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.utils.WSDL2JavaGenerator.getAxisService(WSDL2JavaGenerator.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.execute(Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewWizardAction.run(NewWizardAction.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
```

In fact before that I see this table:
[image]

As you may see the most fields are empty, I can't select service name etc.

One more thing is that I can't access neither default Tomcat's or Axis2 page. I receive 404 error. Tomcat is Running and location of Axis2 is provided as well. In fact, both of the are on the flash memory. I think I can't generate Web service client that's because there must be something wrong with my local tomcat or axis2 ( I can't view the default pages). What do you think about it?

Comment: The problem has been resolved. I only needed to overrride Tomcat 6 folder. It was keeping some sort of remaining data what stoped it from doing its work well.

Comment: hi i have similar problem could please elaborate what do you  mean override tomcat